# Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.Transaction Exception: JDBC commit failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, azure-storage

I am using Windows Azure SQL Server  in my application when i connect to application it shows following error.

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.Transaction
Exception: JDBC commit failed
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:660)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393
)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(CustomizableTraceInterceptor.java:256)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at com.asman.vote.mypaint.service.UserWorksService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$803137ef.yesterdayWinner(<generated>)
        at com.asman.vote.mypaint.controller.MainController.yesterdayWinner(MainController.java:102)
        at com.asman.vote.mypaint.controller.MainController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ff981c3a.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(CustomizableTraceInterceptor.java:256)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
        at com.asman.vote.mypaint.controller.MainController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c20ad12a.yesterdayWinner(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:
426)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC commit failed
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:161)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.commit(SQLServerConnection.java:1936)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)
        ... 54 more
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

..................

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Asman.1234</property>`

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://mzfoe7t5fn.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=VOTEMYPAINT;encrypt=false;packetSize=10240;loginTimeout=300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SQLAdmin@mzfoe7t5fn</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>

        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.UserProfile" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.Purchasedetails" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.Topics" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.AgeGroups" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.Admin" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.TodaysTopic" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.UserWorks" />
        <mapping class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.to.Htmlpages" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### Hibernate-context.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">`
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"

                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="com.asman.vote.mypaint"/>
    <!-- p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" -->
    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
                p:acquireIncrement="10"
                p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                p:maxPoolSize="100000"
                p:maxStatements="100"
                p:minPoolSize="100000" /> --><bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" /></beans>
```

### applicationContext.xml:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">`

```
<!-- <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" /> -->

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
 For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.asman.vote.mypaint" />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    p:maxUploadSize="100000000"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean></mvc:interceptors><!-- Imports logging configuration -->
<import resource="trace-context.xml"/>
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" /> 
<bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" /></beans>
```

### spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1"/>

</beans>
```

### trace-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">`

    <!-- For parsing classes with @Aspect annotation -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="com.asman.vote.mypaint.aop.TraceInterceptor"
        p:enterMessage="Entering $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]($[arguments])"
        p:exitMessage="Leaving $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>

    <aop:config>
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * com.asman.vote.mypaint.service..*(..))"/>
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * com.asman.vote.mypaint.controller..*(..))"/>
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Comment: The trace says that the connection is closed. Use a connection pool that checks connections.

Comment: if i used c3po connection pool in  application.its  not working

Comment: The trace says Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed while it tries to check for closedConnection. Are you sure SQLServer is accepting connections and that the connections being returned from C3P0 are indeed active connections ?

Comment: Can you connect the database server (ping, telnet to correct port), does the server accept remote connections (DB settings), does your firewall pass the connections.. btw. hibernateContext.html?? isn't it also xml? And where is the actual code, these are different confs only.

Comment: you said `when i connect to application it shows following error`.If it's on connection then why is there a failed commit in the stack trace? Is it when connection first made? Does happen on first commit or sometime later? Does it recover without restart?

Comment: You have leaked way too much information. I suggest that next time you at least remove sensitive information that is not relevant to problem resolution, such as username and password.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar error, the easiest solution is to add @Transaction with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

You will not get this error after that and would work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you have opened a hibernate session & you are trying to execute two queries but remember commit of first transaction will not be appearing before start of other.
This might be helpful.
Try to run other query when one transaction commits or use criteria.

Answer (score 0):

use @Transactional above the serviceimpl method

Answer (score 0):

You're using **@Transactional**, to have Spring start, commit and rollback transactions for you, and handle your transactions declaratively. The whole point of this is precisely to not have to start, commit and rollback transactions in the code. So the method implementation should simply be

```
return (List<Login>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Login").list();
```